# Highcharts heatmap chart labels render extremely slow

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to generate a heatmap grid with around 10k grid cells. The heatmap renders in under a second without dataLabels. However if I enable dataLabels, which are necessary for my project, the same heatmap takes 10 seconds to render. I tried setting useHTML to true, and that renders in 30+ seconds. I'm not doing any work within the dataLabel rendering. Is there any way to speed this up?

[image: Image of part of grid - my grid is 270 rows]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example with 10k cells in the heatmap with enabled data labels is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dddqrb9f/).

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'heatmap'
  },

  xAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 99
  },

  series: [{
    data: data,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }]
});
```

1. No-opt rendering time: 33.5 s

[image: Profiling heatmap]

From the profiler I can say thet there are two good candidates for optimization.

2. Rendering with overlapping labels: 10.4 s

   ```
   dataLabels: {
     enabled: true,
     allowOverlap: true
   }
   ```
3. No textOutline: 8.56 s

   ```
   dataLabels: {
     enabled: true,
     allowOverlap: true,
     shadow: false,
     style: {
       textOutline: null,
       color: 'black'
     }
   },
   ```

The other candidate is about setting zIndex for the data labels, I cannot see how to optimize it without changing internal Highcharts method responsible for drawing data labels. You can wrap `drawDataLabels` method and remove the part for setting label's zIndex.

4. Without zIndex: 1.62 s

   ```
   attr = {
     //align: align,

     fill: options.backgroundColor,
     stroke: options.borderColor,
     'stroke-width': options.borderWidth,

     r: options.borderRadius || 0,
     rotation: rotation,
     padding: options.padding
     //    zIndex: 1 /* commenting this part gives a few good seconds */
   };
   ```

full example: http://jsfiddle.net/dddqrb9f/1/

I commented only one line in the function but you can remove additional features if you don't need them - e.g. if you don't need labels, you can render text only.

```
  if (!dataLabel) {
      dataLabel = point.dataLabel = renderer['text']
```

5. Text instead of labels: 0.864 s

example: http://jsfiddle.net/dddqrb9f/2/

Comment: Amazing! Currently doing ok with hover labels. Will circle back here when I am ready to try again with data labels. Be sure to let Highcharts know about these optimizations (unless you work for them.) Thanks!